# Equivalent of documentElement.innerHTML for XML

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, innerhtml

I have some javascript that runs in Firefox and accesses the contents of a second tab. I do not have control of the contents of the second tab.

When the second tab is HTML. I am able to read the contents of the tab as a string and also clear the tab contents using

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this when there is an XML document loaded in the second tab (i.e. no enclosing html tag so innerHTML doesnt work). The two things I need to do are: (1) read tab contents, (2) clear tab contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) to convert a node tree to a string and [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOMParser) to convert a string to a node tree. As far as I know, they only work in Firefox, but as of Firefox 4, I believe they work in HTML documents as well as XML documents. Note that to clear nodes you can just use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Comment: Thanks. that worked. In case its useful for anyone, to delete contents of window I used: `document.documentElement.parentNode.removeChild(document.documentElement)`

Comment: @spiderplant0 That's the same as `document.removeChild(document.documentElement)`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `element.nodeValue`

Edit: As pointed out in the comments this is not possible due to limitations detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue

Comment: I see ... I will leave this answer as a reference for others. (unless a more experienced user thinks otherwise)